# Ruby Error installing af: failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby

I wanna deploy my grails application on AppFog. To do this, I've installed Ruby 22 x64 and devkit mengv64. I've extracted devkit.7z to C:\ruby, done commands: `dk.rb install`,`dk.rb init`. Then, I entered a command: `gem install af`,
but I got such error: Error installing af: failed to build gem native extension. How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is often an issue with the escape_utils gem. This a general limitation of RubyGems. If there's a problem with a gem dependencies, new installs of the af gem or updates to any of its gem dependencies can screw things up. That's why AppFog v2 is testing a binary executable to avoid this mess.

That being said, the general practice for installing on Windows is to [install the Ruby environment](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) you want and install the [appropriate dev kit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). When that's done, you'll need to find the **Ruby Enabled Command Prompt**. Usually, `Start > Programs > Ruby*`. Everything below should now be done from there:

1. `ruby dk.rb install`
2. `ruby dk.rb init`
3. `gem update --system`
4. `gem install escape_utils -v 1.0.1`

   - This gem regularly has problems, especially for Windows, so this is usually the best version to go with for the time being.
5. `gem install af`

---

Here's AF's article for installing the gem on Windows: [Installing the AF CLI Tool on Windows](https://support.appfog.com/hc/en-us/articles/205027897).

Comment: you have saved my life! the step 4 did the trick! thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Either the App Fog gem requires a native extension, or one of its dependencies does.

Does the error show which gem is failing?

According to [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/af/versions/0.3.22), there are some dependencies. I don't see which one would require a native extension.

So, you may want to try installing the dependencies and see if one of them fails.